# add alert to Postmail when successfull or error in HTML / JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kinda new in HTML, I am using postmail to send myself an email after submitting a form like this:

The HTML:

```
<form action="https://postmail.invotes.com/send" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <input id="subject" type="hidden" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="New Request" />
    <textarea id="message" name="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input id="success" type="hidden" name="success_url" value=".?message=Email+Successfully+Sent%21&isError=0" />
    <input id="error" type="hidden" name="error_url" value=".?message=Email+could+not+be+sent.&isError=1" />
    <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

I added a JS as suggested by postmail website:

```
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_form");
var form = document.getElementById("contact_form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    submitButton.value = "Sending...";
    submitButton.disabled = true;
  }, 1);
  //form.reset();
});
```

Although, my form is at <my_url>/contact. But when it is successfull, it redirects to:

```
<my_url>/?message=Email+Successfully+Sent%21&isError=0
```

And when there is an error, it redirects to:

```
<my-url>/?message=Email+could+not+be+sent.&isError=1
```

I would like instead to stay on the page, reset the form and display an alert "message successfully send" or "error when submitting the form".

Any idea how I could do that please?

Answer (score 0):

first you need add :

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault() //<--with this your page won't reload on submit
  setTimeout(function() {
    submitButton.value = "Sending...";
    submitButton.disabled = true;
  }, 1);
  //form.reset();
});
```

second :

```
<form action="https://postmail.invotes.com/send" method="post" id="contact_form">
    <input id="subject" type="hidden" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="New Request" />
    <textarea id="message" name="text" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <input id="success" type="hidden" name="success_url" value=".?message=Email+Successfully+Sent%21&isError=0" /> //<-- this element cause redirect in case of successs
    <input id="error" type="hidden" name="error_url" value=".?message=Email+could+not+be+sent.&isError=1" /> //<-- this element cause redirect in case of error
    <input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

you can modify this two for changing redirect Behavior

Comment: Where and how could I add form.reset(); "alert("Message Sent Succesfully!");" and alert("Error With Message!");, please?

Comment: i checked network process of page postmail api sends you redirected page as response base on error or success of request  basically you can't control response they send you can check response in network tab in browser console

Comment: Is there a way then to display the alert messages when it redirects based on the new url ?